Using F result for get key
I have dict like {product_id: count}.
For example cart_items = {1: 150}. This dict represents customer basket.
I also have product model with count field. It's representing stock balances.
I want to get products that is in dict and update their quantity according to values in dict.
I get products like this :
products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=cart_items)
And I want to update the quantity like this:
products.update(count=dict.get(F("id"))
But it doesn't work.
Thx!

You can do this, but it is very bad idea. Typically you make JOINs in the database, since databases are optimized for this.

It's not clear what you want. Trying to do products.update(count=dict.get(F("id")) suggests you want to update the counts in the database, but you said in replies that is not what you want.

look. I want to get a queryset from the database. Change the count attribute of the products. Then pass this queriset to the serialiser and send it to the front end.
Is that clearer?)

I have a separate dictionary containing a pair of product id and its quantity. And I need to change the quantity value in the queryset according to this dictionary.

@Anentropic: then replace .update(..) with .annotate(..).

@Андрей you can't modify the queryset in the way you want, instead you need to fetch the results into a python list and modify the individual Product instances in the list

It also seems weird that count field on the model now means one of two different things, either the stock quantity in the db, or the amount added to the cart by user.  Maybe it would be clearer to treat them separately.

You can do this, but it is very bad idea. Typically you make JOINs in the database, since databases are optimized for this. You can however work with a Case-When expression [Django-doc] for this:
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

products.update(
    count=Case(*[When(pk=k, then=Value(v)) for k, v in my_dict.items()])
)
This will thus "unwind" the my_dict into a (likely) long sequence of CASE WHEN … THEN …s. This will however result in linear search slowing down the updating process.

I'm not going to record the results in a database. I need to get the results from the database, change the values and give them to the serialiser and the front end. The idea is this.
What is the best way to do it then?
I tried it this way, but the result is not saved....
(
setattr(product, "count", int(cart_items.get(str(product.id))))
for product in products
)

Or is it better to convert models to JSON and change the quantity there and send further?

@Андрей: exactly the same, you can mimic a dictionary lookup for my_dict with the Case(...).

@Андрей: hell no, JSON blobs in relational databases are often a severe problem: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/non-atomic-jsonfield-s.html
